# Finding special integer, code not efficient enough

Tags: java

I'm on my way of solving euler problem 108, therefore I want to find the integer `n` so that that there are 1000 combinations of: `1/i + 1/t = 1/n` (`i` and `t` are random numbers). My code:

```
int counter = 0;

    for (int n = 10000; n < 200000; n++) {
        for (int i = n; i < 1000000; i++) {
            for (int t = i; t < 1000000; t++) {
                if ((n * (i + t)) == (i * t)) {                     
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 1000) {
                        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
                        System.out.println("N: " + n);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }                       
                }
            }           
        }   
        counter = 0;
    }
```

However, this does not terminate. How come? I reset the counter for each round and check if it ever reaches the value 1000.

Comment: The spirit of ProjectEuler is to find the answers on your own.

Comment: There are 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 * 200,000 iterations, that's `2e17` iterations. Even if you are running 100 million iterations per second that's still over 60 years...

Comment: You need at least a mainframe to terminate this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop takes too much time to terminate.

You have a considerable number of steps inside each loop, which is computed with multiplication in your time complexity (`O(loopIter1*loopIter2*loopIter3)`), leading to a considerable matter of time.

As @BorisTheSpider mentioned, your loops will result to 2e17 iterations, which requires a few years (or decades) to terminate - well, it is not suggested to wait that much :)

Consider also that you probably exceed an integer variable [beyond its max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131131/what-happens-when-you-increment-an-integer-beyond-its-max-value).
While this might not lead to an overflow or underflow in Java, it can still lead to unexpected behavior, as of after an integer variable reaches `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is 2^32 - 1), an increment will make its value `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and so on.

In a case of int max value exceeding as described above, some checks may fail: think that `Integer.MAX_VALUE > 1000`, but `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` will lead to `Integer.MIN_VALUE < 1000`.

In your code it does not seem to affect it direcly, but I would seriously consider this effect in your computations.

Comment: What kind of adjustments are then needed? I cannot understand how I can make this code more efficient considering that it basically only consists of there for-loops.

Comment: @JavaCoder Project Euler challenges are **always** about understanding the underlying mathematics and not brute force. In fact, they are specifically _designed_ to not be brute-forceable.