# Why the program is not throwing an exception when there is an overflow or underflow

Tags: java, exception, integer-overflow

When the maximum value of integer is exceeded (overflow) then the minimum value is assigned to it.
Ex- `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1);` Output: `-2147483648`
Here instead of throwing an exception, the program returns an incorrect value.
How does this feature help the programmers or designers in any way?

Comment: This is not an incorrect value, it is absolutely correct - an Integer in Java is a signed 32 bit number - adding 1 to its MAX value loops it back round to its lowest value .. which it what you've got ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5131206/4252352

Comment: Absolutely right on data type point of view @MarkKeen. But when a developer writes code for a calculation (like: int x=3*1000000000) then he do not expect a negative value to be assigned to the variable x. That why I say it as a wrong value on developer point of view. I faced this problem in my project while calculating 3% of a number. I was in misconception that java will through an exception or error but will never calculate a wrong result.

Comment: So, this is just an opinion on how'd you prefer the overflow to work : Throw an exception, rather than producing an unexpected result? This is an unanswerable question - This is how it works and you already know this, you just have work accordingly, i.e. coding checking / testing / correct variable assigning (int, long etc..). I can't say that there is a programming language out there that does exactly as every person wants and expects ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It makes code run faster, by not needing to check for overflow after every single arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't think the original implementers of java wanted the overhead of having to check to see if a computation caused an overflow. You can check programatically. For example, [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

It's how traditional C and C++ will handles integers as well, so there is a precedent.