# Why do I get IndexOutOfBoundsException at index = -2147483648 (= Integer.MIN_VALUE)?

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

The following code runs until it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundException`stating `h` is `-2147483648`.

At the beginning `h=0`and it only gets incremented, never decremented. How could it become negative?

```
float[] powerArray = new float[8760];
int h = 0;
for (TShortIterator it = heightData.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    short wspeed = it.next();
    if (h < 8760) {                 
        powerArray[h] = Math.min(wspeed, 4);
    }
    h++;
}
```

Comment: This is kinda weird to iterate with a range based loop like that

Comment: That's a poor quality question and answer. In the current state, the correct answer is just `because array index has to be between 0 and the array length, and -2147483648 is not`

Comment: I did not write the original code but had to handle it.

Comment: @Jhamon: Write it as answer and I'll accept it. :) The purpose of this question is to get a result when searching for indexoutoufboundexception and -2147483648.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs for the case that the iterator has more entries than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

`h` is incremented until it reaches `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. On the next increment, the integer is overflown and becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE=-2147483648`.

Then the expression `powerArray[-2147483648]` fails due to the negative index.

Comment: Did you ask and answer at the same time? Why would you ask if you knew the answer?

Comment: @Aidin There's nothing wrong with [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @jesper Yes, I get that. But he does it literally the same minute that he asks

Comment: @Aidin Stack allows this, if you have something non-duplicate and useful then you can answer it yourself but in this case , since there is no code about what `getHeightData(sensorHight)`  does, so not quite sure about it

Comment: @Aidin Yes, so what? SO even has a special option to let you post the question and answer at the same time.

Comment: Yes. It took me some time to solve the issue. Searching for IndexOutOfBoundException and iterator did not help.... so I thought the answer might help others facing similar issues. It's also a note for future me to not forget about it. :)

Comment: @Jesper Ok, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: the answer was already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131131/what-happens-when-you-increment-an-integer-beyond-its-max-value) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Comment: Same answer but different question... Once I knew that the int limit is the issue ... yes... then the solution was easy.