# Why is the integer comparision giving the wrong results?

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve a problem which requires me to write a function called `mySqrt` of the form `int mySqrt(int x)`.

I am supposed  to compute and return the square root of x, where x is guaranteed to be a non-negative integer.

Since the return type is an integer, the decimal digits are truncated and only the integer part of the result is returned.

I tried to implement a straightforward algorithm where I start from `i=0` and then increment the value of `i` until `$i*i<=x$` and then return `i-1`.

```
public int mySqrt(int x) {
    int i=0;
    while(i*i<=x){
        i++;
    }
    return (i-1);
}
```

I have an idea of what is happening but I really can't understand why. 
When i is large enough such that `i^2 >2^31-1` the comparison in the while loop `(i*i<=x)` for `x=2147395600` (which is less that `2^31-1`) gives me a true. Why would that be? And as a consequence I am getting junk results. What is exactly happening when I try to evaluate (`i^2<=x`) when `i^2` can no longer be stored in an int?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131131/what-happens-when-you-increment-an-integer-beyond-its-max-value

Comment: Hint: try logging the result of `i * i` in your loop.

Comment: Integer overflow. You wrap back to negative.

Comment: So i resolved it by typecasting i*i to a long. Thank you